# Is it possible to group items in a NSPopupButton?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm trying to display a list of system voices, but I'd like to group them by region.

This is an example of select in html.

[image: Drop down menu with grouped items]

Ideally I'd like to create a dropdown that is similar to accessibility language selection.

[image]

Is there any way to replicate this in Interface Builder / swift?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Update:

The reason for this, is because I am displaying a list of speech voices to the user.  At the moment, it mixes all the regions together, which is very confusing.

[image: voice drop down]

There is an update I'm working on, where I can display "English (United Kingdom)", but I'd like to group them up before releasing it.

Comment: I don't think there's an off-the-shelf control like that.  You should be able to build it using a table view though. (I work mostly in iOS these days so my Mac Cocoa is getting rusty.)

Comment: @DuncanC is right. Your second screenshot appears to be an `NSTableView` shown inside a modal sheet. So if that's what you're trying to replicate, that's where you should start.

Comment: @TheNextman, I don't remember. Do NSTableViews support sections using IndexPath values like iOS table views do, or do you have to create that functionality yourself? Looking at the data source methods, it looks like they only take a row value so you have to create the section structure yourself.

Comment: After further digging I found that no, `NSTableView` does **not** support sections. I found this link where somebody did the hard work: https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/05/29/lets-talk-about-sections-for-nstableview/

Comment: Well, it supports group rows: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1526676-tableview?language=objc. The API is not the same and not as nice as on iOS (`NSTableView` predates `UITableView`), and you could have a hard time depending on how your data is structured

Comment: I checked with Accessibility Inspector, and the voice table in your second screenshot is an `NSTableView`

Comment: I have created group rows before with NSTableView, which is a start. Thought it's nice to see it done properly.
 Any idea how go displaying it like the popupbutton?

Comment: I know it seems hacky, but I've seen apps (some from Apple, IIRC) that simply prepend spaces to the indented items and disable the group header items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code groups menu, but not like the way you mentioned.

```
let items = [["First","Second"],["First","Second"],["First","Second"]]

lazy var addNewViewButton : NSPopUpButton = {
    let popupButton = NSPopUpButton()

    let firstMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "First Group", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    let secondMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Second Group", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    let thirdMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Third Group", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")

    let superMenu = NSMenu()
    superMenu.addItem(firstMenuItem)
    superMenu.addItem(secondMenuItem)
    superMenu.addItem(thirdMenuItem)

    for (index,item) in items.enumerated()
    {
        let menu = NSMenu()
        for title in item
        {
            let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: title, action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
            menuItem.target = self
            menu.addItem(menuItem)
        }
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        superMenu.setSubmenu(menu, for: superMenu.items[index])
    }
    popupButton.menu = superMenu

    popupButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return popupButton
}()
```

Add the popupbutton in your code and you will get results like this

[image]

Each one will be having its own items inside.

Comment: At this point, anything is better than what I currently have.
Thank you.

Comment: The menu is displaying perfectly, however whenever I select an item it defaults back to the first entry. :(

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465965/how-do-i-keep-nsmenuitem-selected-in-a-nspopover-with-nsmenu/53470482#53470482

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to offer an answer in Objective-C because I'm not up on Swift. Sorry... You ought to be able to translate it easily enough, though, or I'm sure someone here can do it.

So, I managed this by making a subclass of NSMenu with the following method:

```
@implementation MenuWithSections

- (NSMenuItem*)insertItemWithTitle:(NSString*)aString action:(SEL)aSelector keyEquivalent:(NSString*)keyEquiv atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSMenuItem * item;
    NSString * adjustedString;

    if ([aString isEqualToString:menuDividerString]) {
        NSMenuItem *separator = [NSMenuItem separatorItem];
        [self insertItem:separator atIndex:index];
        return separator;
    } else if ([aString hasPrefix:menuSectionHeaderPrefix]) {
        adjustedString = [[aString substringFromIndex:menuSectionHeaderPrefix.length] capitalizedString];
        NSMenuItem * sectionHead =  [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:adjustedString
                                                           action:nil
                                                    keyEquivalent:@""];
        sectionHead.enabled = NO;
        sectionHead.indentationLevel = 0;
        [self insertItem:sectionHead atIndex:index];
        return sectionHead;
    } 

    item = [super insertItemWithTitle:aString action:aSelector keyEquivalent:keyEquiv atIndex:index];
    item.indentationLevel = 1;
    return item;
}

@end
```

`menuDividerString` in my case is @"----", and `menuSectionHeaderPrefix` is @".."; see the examples below.

To make it work, do three things:

1. In IB, drill down the popup button until you see its menu, and set the class of the menu to 'MenuWithSections'.
   [popup button drill-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yreXI.png)
2. Turn off the popup button's 'autoenable' feature (click it off in the 'Attributes' tab of IB, or set it to NO programmatically)
3. Pass in modified strings using the above constants to get the desired effect.

In other words, to get the look you want in your question, pass the popup button titles like so:

```
[self.popbutton addItemsWithTitles:@[ @"..swedish cars", @"Volvo", @"Saab", @"..German cars", @"Mercedes", @"Audi"]];
```

[sectioned popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GElM1.png)

or if you want a divider-line between the two groups, use:

```
[self.popbutton addItemsWithTitles:@[ @"..swedish cars", @"Volvo", @"Saab", @"----", @"..German cars", @"Mercedes", @"Audi"]];
```

[sectioned popup with divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHBkL.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the group heading, you can use the following code

```
let items = [["First","Second"],["First","Second"],["First","Second"]]

lazy var addNewViewButton : NSPopUpButton = {
    let popupButton = NSPopUpButton()

    let menu = NSMenu()
    for item in items
    {
        for title in item
        {
            let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: title, action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
            menuItem.target = self
            menu.addItem(menuItem)
        }
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
    }
    popupButton.menu = menu

    popupButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return popupButton
}()
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture with my current issue.  Hopefully it'll make sense why your other answer is preferable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that NSPopupButton has a .menu!  In my particular case I was stuck on not being able to add separator menu items directly to the popup class .addItem(withTitle:), and it was enough to just do `popupButton.menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())`.